# backdrop-filter: blur renders differently in puppeteer headless vs non-headless screenshot

Tags: puppeteer

When I apply `backdrop-filter: blur(15px)` and take a screenshot using puppeteer, this is what I get in non-headless mode, which is consistent with how I see it in Chrome:

[image: Results in Chrome and in non-headless puppeteer screenshot]

But when I screenshot the same page in headless mode, I get this image:

[image: The backdrop filter tapers off toward the edges of the div]

As you can see, the backdrop filter effect tapers off toward the edges of the div.

What gives?

Comment: What command line do you use ? What is your html css ?

Answer (score 2):

I use chrome-stable on ubuntu and for me backdrop filter not working at all.

Comment: i tried on windows and blur() does not work at all....

Answer (score 0):

I use :

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome  ... --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox --no-margins --print-background  ...
```

and backdrop-filter does not render at all neither

I also setup a AWS Lambda puppeteer with  :

```
const puppeteerArgs = [
  "--disable-gpu",
  "--hide-scrollbars",
  "--no-sandbox",
  "--no-zygote",
  "--use-gl=swiftshader",
  "--window-size=1920,1080",
  "--single-process",
];
```

and the result is the same : backdrop-filter has no effect at all.

EDIT : It's linked to a Chrome bug and a limitation of PDF files (no background blurring in pdf) : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1420589